# libgdx ProgressBar rotation does not work

Tags: java, rotation, libgdx, actor

The .setRotation() or .rotateBy() functions work on other Actor classes but not on ProgressBar objects.

Am I missing something here?

```
public void create() {
    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    skin = new Skin();
    Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(10, 10, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    pixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    pixmap.fill();
    skin.add("white", new Texture(pixmap));

    TextureRegionDrawable textureBar = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("blue.jpg")))); // Just a blue square
    ProgressBar.ProgressBarStyle barStyle = new ProgressBar.ProgressBarStyle(skin.newDrawable("white", Color.DARK_GRAY), textureBar);
    progressBar = new ProgressBar(0,10,0.5f,false, barStyle);
    progressBar.setPosition(10, 10);
    progressBar.setSize(290, progressBar.getPrefHeight());
    progressBar.setAnimateDuration(2);
    progressBar.setValue(5);
    progressBar.setRotation(45); // Should rotate the bar

    stage.addActor(progressBar);
}
```

[image: The bar stays horizontal even if I set the rotation.]

Also if I call .getRotation() I get whatever I set it previously so I'm not sure what is the problem here.

Comment: The progress bar itself is designed to render itself horizontally and vertically and does not allow generic roation (see https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ProgressBar.java#L129).  Have your tried putting it in some containment and rotate this instead?

Comment: Most of the UI widgets don't support arbitrary rotation because they rely on OpenGL scissoring for cropping.

Comment: @cfrick ahh that must be it. I'll try it when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

[Most UI widgets cannot be transformed directly](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#rotation-and-scale), due to performance reasons. There are still getters/setters for rotation though, this can be confusing.

However it is possible to put them in a `Group` and transform the group.

```
ProgressBar progressBar = ...
Group g = new Group();
g.addActor(progressBar);
g.setRotation(45);

stage.addActor(g);
```